# How can I view old status messages in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have this feeling that if I knew the correct terminology here, I wouldn't need to ask this question and Google would suffice. Alas.

Using http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2423, when I run the ':Gist' command, the plugin prints the link to the gist at the bottom of the terminal window, where one would normally enter commands. I'm not sure what this is called. I can't select the text there and thus can't copy it, and the moment I do something else, the text disappears and gets replaced with the normal mode text.

I know there is q: for viewing old commands, but is there some way that I can view old messages like the one that gist.vim spits out? Or is there at least some magical way that I can copy that beautiful text before I do something else and it disappears?

If it is relevant, I'm on OS X Lion and running Vim in iTerm. Nothing special.

Comment: I don't know about iTerm, but in Linux xterm you can shift-click-drag to select text, without sending any mouse message to Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `:help Gist`, there is a setting that automatically copies the gist link to your clipboard with `:Gist -c`

```
If you set g:gist_clip_command, gist.vim will copy the gist code with option '-c'.

Mac:

let g:gist_clip_command = 'pbcopy'

Linux:

let g:gist_clip_command = 'xclip -selection clipboard'

Others (cygwin?):

let g:gist_clip_command = 'putclip'
```

Add this to your `~/.vimrc` and you're good to go.

**Edit:**

Found a hackish solution.

Go to `gist.vim` and find this function.

```
function! s:GistPost(user, token, content, private)

  " find GistID: in content, then we should just update

  ...  

  let location = substitute(location, '^[^:]\+: ', '', '')
  if len(location) > 0 && location =~ '^\(http\|https\):\/\/gist\.github\.com\/'
    redraw
    echo 'Done: '.location
  else

  ...

  return location
endfunction
```

Change `echo` to `echomsg`.

```
  if len(location) > 0 && location =~ '^\(http\|https\):\/\/gist\.github\.com\/'
    redraw
    echomsg 'Done: '.location
```

Now restart vim, and after entering `:Gist`, type `:message` to get the link from the message-history. The message-history logs everything from `echomsg` and `echoerr` for that session.

Comment: Right, I did that. The question is still relevant though.

Comment: @Rayne See edit :)

Answer (score 26):

I was looking for any answer for your question due to a different plugin.  I stumbled upon the name of the message output in `:h message`.

If your vim window is still open, it looks like you can hit `g<` to see the last message.

I think `:messages` works too.

Comment: Although the answer selected as the correct one is specific for the plugin that was asked, I think your answer is a better one, because it is generic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sent a fix to the plugin author about this. https://github.com/mattn/gist-vim/pull/49